# How does BERT deal with catastrophic forgetting?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, transfer-learning

In the [ULMFit paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.06146) authors propose a strategy of gradual unfreezing in order to deal with catastrophic forgetting. That is, when the model starts be fine-tuned according to a downstream task, there is the danger of forgetting information on lower layers. Although [Google's BERT](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04805) is also a pre-trained language model, which makes use of fine-tuning for downstream tasks, authors don't mention this phenomenon. Why is that the case? Is BERT immune to it? Or does it deal with this in another way?

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid overfitting to the finetuning data (which is what the authors of ULMFiT focus on when they refer to catastrophic forgetting), these measures are normally taken for BERT:

- Multiple BERT models are trained (random restarts), and the one with the best validation performance is chosen.
- The bias compensation in the Adam optimizer is omitted, leading to the so-called "BERTAdam". This turned to be one of the main sources of BERT finetuning instability, as shown in [*On the Stability of Fine-tuning BERT: Misconceptions, Explanations, and Strong Baselines*](https://www.lsv.uni-saarland.de/wp-content/publications/2020/On_the_Stability_of_Fine-tuning_BERT_preprint.pdf) and in [*Revisiting Few-sample BERT Fine-tuning*](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.05987), so it's better to stick to Adam or AdamW with bias compensation.
- Only around 3 finetuning epochs were used. This turned to be needed only because of the omission of the bias compensation (see previous bullet and the referred articles).

Comment: Could the downvoter explain why this answer deserves a downvote?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no neural network can be immune to catastrophic forgetting during fine-tuning (which is essentially controlled retraining).

The key is to not fine tune the pretrained model for longer epochs, or with higher learning rates. This ensures that the learned knowledge from the lower layers is preserved more or less intact, while also helping the model learn from the new data used for fine-tuning, as mentioned here : https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/1019